# PHP included file but Undefined variable

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, and i start to use XAMPP to build the site. I have code below

db.php:

```
<?php
    $hostName='localhost';
    $userName='xxxxxxxxx';
    $userPass='xxxxxxxxx';
?>
```

and a test.php:

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';
    echo $hostName;
?>
```

but now it show me **Notice: Undefined variable: hostName**

what i found is the register_globals need to set "on" in php.ini, but after i set, the XAMPP show: **Directive 'register_globals' is no longer available in PHP** when i restart XAMPP.

i move the same code to Hosting24 but it's work, anyone can help?

Comment: Are the files in the same folder? Btw, this is not related to `register_globals` which is indeed removed from PHP.

Comment: yes, both file in the same folder

Comment: try to print something like echo "hi" in db.php.and run test.php.this will show wether db.php is added to your file or not

Comment: try using `require` instead of `include` - if you get an error, there is a problem loading the `db.php` file (could be caused by a lot of things)

Comment: @DeepakSrinivasan yes, but it did not print anything, so i use get_included_files() to show the file that included, 'db.php' is in the list.

Comment: @yossarian changed, but did not fix. =(

Comment: Is this the real code, copied here using the clipboard, and the real file names? What you describe can only happen if you've changed the case of a variable or file (`$hostName` != `$hostname`).

Comment: almost the same, i'm sure that variable name is no mistake.

Comment: @crossRT Well, I'd say that "almost the same" is not enough given that the code you've posted does not exhibit the behaviour you describe...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario sorry, i write the wrong sentense @@
i'm pretty sure the variable name is no mistake, both is same.

Comment: I had this same problem, but it was because test.php was with <? code ?> without the php.

Answer (score 6):

I just got bit by a similar problem - definitely not OP's problem but falls under the question's title.

In my case I had PHP short tags disabled on the server, but the included file accidentally used short tags. When the file was included, functions were undefined and there were no inclusion errors. What I think happens in this situation is that the file is included but treated as an empty file.

If you have an "undefined" problem after inclusion/requirement, check your file tags - just in case.

Comment: I had same issue just recently, though I found the problem after some efforts. your statement is absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that this can happen is if the file `db.php` is not included properly. Check your log files for why this happens.

When you include a file PHP treats this file as if you copy/pasted the code directly into the including file. So all your variables defined in the included file will have the same scope as the including file and hence are available.

In your example, it should just work. So my answer would be: check your log files for include errors. Make sure logging is set to FULL.

Comment: i use get_required_files() and the 'db.php' is in the list.
may i know how to check the log file? sorry for i'm pretty new to PHP

Comment: Your log file is stored in: `\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`. If it's not there, check the `error_log` setting that you can get by running `phpinfo()`. It's always good practice to check the log files when you run into problems :)

Comment: yeah, i found, thanks for advice. =D
But the log file did not have relevent event about the undefined variable:(

Comment: Nothing related to `db.php`? Make sure your error level is set to max

Comment: ya, nothing even if i search in the log file.
this problem making me crazy, same code but move to Hosting24 is work. @@

Comment: Ok - so it worked on your XAMPP instance which was running locally I assume? And now you moved it to a hoster and it doesn't work anymore? In that case, don't check your XAMPP logs, but check the logs of the hoster company :)

Comment: No, contrary. the code works on hoster company but XAMPP local doesn't work. :(

Comment: Check the php settings on the hoster and compare it to your local php settings. There is something wrong with your XAMPP settings, I can't find any other reason (see my answer above)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, what happened to be the issue was the **file access permissions** for the files

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hi @JoJoe for you kind information, it does answer to the question asked by the author. There is nothing to elaborate. This is surely one of the reasons that may cause the erratic issue faced here.  Any novice PHP developer may also get what i meant. If you guess i am wrong then why don't you provide a answer rather then being rude to a new contributor to community. Warm Regards.

Comment: Hey @acoustichead, don't take this too personal, this is an automatically generated text by SO. Someone flagged your answer as low quality (perhaps because of its length), it showed up in the review queue and when I reviewed it, I marked it as "should be a comment". I did this because I thought it lacked the necessary length and explanatory depth to qualify as an answer. The system then automatically comments on the answer, admittedly not using the best choice of words, but it just isn't that flexible. If the other reviewers think your answer is fine, absolutely nothing will happen. :)

Comment: oh i'm sorry, this auto generated comment reads too intimidating for a new user :P

Answer (score -1):

Try using `require_once('db.php')` instead of include.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: In the `test.php` , instead of `include 'include.php';` , replace it with `require_once('db.php');`